# React-select: Can't get the name of a newly created element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have implemented a dropdown menu with search and the possibility of creating an item:

```
        <Creatable
          cacheOptions
          options={interests}
          isMulti
          defaultOptions
          onInputChange={this.handleInterestsInputChange}
          onChange={this.onSelectedInterest}
        />
```

[image]
When a user selects an existing option (interest) or creates a new one, this gets triggered:

```
  onSelectedInterest(all_selected_interests, action_details) {
    const { action } = action_details;
    if (action == "select-option") {
      // Do something
    } else if (action == "create-option") {
      console.log(
        " ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 470 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~ onSelectedInterest ~ action_details",
        action_details
      );
      console.log(
        " ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 470 ~ EditProfileInSettings ~ onSelectedInterest ~ all_selected_interests",
        all_selected_interests
      );
    }
  }
```

The problem is when `(action == "create-option")`, I cannot retrieve the name of the newly created option. This is what gets logged:

> ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 470 ~ EditProfileInSettings
> ~ onSelectedInterest ~ action_details {action: "create-option", name:
> undefined}
>
> ~ file: EditProfileInSettings.js ~ line 470 ~ EditProfileInSettings
> ~ onSelectedInterest ~ all_selected_interests  [{…}] 0: {label:
> "new_option_name", value: "new_option_name", **isNew**: true} length:
> 1
> **proto**: Array(0)

It does get logged with `all_selected_interests`, but if there are other options, then it will be logged with them.
So in order to retrieve I will have to do it manually.

In the case of `select-option`, the select option gets logged in `action_details`. So I can retrieve it directly from there.

It's a bit strange that it's not the same for create-option.